# Load a sameorigin webpage in another website using iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I want to display [this webpage](https://onlineadmission.ignou.ac.in/onlinerr/StudentReRegistrationForm.aspx) in my application.

But i got this error Refused to display https://onlineadmission.ignou.ac.in/onlinerr/StudentReRegistrationForm.aspx in a frame because it set `X-Frame-Options` to `sameorigin`.
Please help me out how to display that page in my application.

```
<iframe name="form-target" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://onlineadmission.ignou.ac.in/onlinerr/StudentReRegistrationForm.aspx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" srcolling="no"  target='_top'></iframe>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options - this is a server-side header set by the site administrator / developer. The site doesn't want to allow you to load that page in a frame within a remote site. That's their choice. Usually it's done as a measure to enhance their security. I doubt there is anything you can do about it.

Comment: i read this article but my problem not solved

Comment: I know it won't solve your problem. My point about the article is that it's not possible to solve your problem - the other site is configured not to permit what you want to do.

Comment: ok thank for the rply

Answer (score 0):

Well, if that would work the way you want, then The clickjacking attack would be possible too.Thats why we have security for.

There is an interesting article about this: [iframe-loading](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/07/20/block-iframe-loading/)

You can check [Clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) for more informations.

Or [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet) for those, who wants to know, how to prevent clickjacking attack.

Comment: i need solution i try everthing but my problem remain same